# Handling decimals in C without float

Tags: c, microcontroller, bitwise-operators

I have a problem in C, I am not allowed to use floats as the microcontroller it will be flashed does not support that data type. Now all my integers are being rounded off as it should. How do I handle this case?

A short research indicates using bit wise operation such as left shift and right shift. I know what are these operations. But I do not know how to use these operations to achieve what I want.

Comment: It depends on how you plan to use those values.  What exactly is your use case?

Comment: What kind of values do you have? If you know you will have e.g. two decimals (e.g. US currency amounts), the typical strategy is to multiply everything by 100 and think of it as integral cents instead of fractional dollars.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: Only you can decide what you have to do and therefore the best way to do it...

Comment: Even if the microcontroller does not support floating point in hardware, the C libraries for your development tool chain probably support floating point math in software.  Is there a reason you're not allowed to use software floating point libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the [Q number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29).

You will get some results if you google "Q number format" or some variations.
It is often used for some DSP related topics in C. [Here](http://blog.numerix-dsp.com/2015/01/introduction-to-q-format-number-system.html) another blog post that explains that number format and [here](http://blog.numerix-dsp.com/2015/01/c-code-to-implement-q-format-number.html) is an example code implementation for q-numbers in C.

In general you can say that q-numbers represent a number between -1 and 1 without using floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a microcontroller don't have a floating point unit, everything works with integers. But its up to you which unit you like for your integers.

For example:
100 could be 100 cm or 1,00 m

1000 could be 100,0 cm or 1,000 m  and so on..

Please have a look at the description:
[electronic.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/how-are-numbers-with-decimal-point-handled-in-an-mcu)